# Use Icons from diffrenet place in android jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using some icons from drawable using `painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon_id)` which is `Painter` object and have some icons from material library `Icons.Default.Home` which is an `ImageVector` object. I want to do this as below

```kotlin
data class MenuItem(val icon:Painter, val label:String)

@Composable
fun renderMenu(items: List<MenuItem>){
    // do some menu staff here
}

// here i want to send the data from different places

renderMenu(items = listOf(MenuItem(painterResource(R.drawable.menu_1), "Menu 1"), MenuItem(Icons.Default.Home, "Menu 2")))
```

Do anyone know how i can do this in jetpack compose?

Answer (score 1):

You can update your `MenuItem` class to receive `ImageVector` as variable instead of `Painter` object and assign your `ImageVector` from resources like this:

```
ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable. menu_1)
```

And that should do the trick for you.